# tableview is connected to datasource and delegate - how

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i am new to iOS, this may seem like a basic question. I have been working through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) and I have no idea how the tableview is connected to the code. The sample project can be [downloaded here](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/WeatherStarter.zip).

I was my understanding that you need to extend UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource in the code, then in the storyboard you can drag from the tableview to them.

But what is perplexing is that the sample project does not extend UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource at all, therefore, how is the tableview in the story board connected to the code ?

Comment: just updated my question, please refresh your page

Comment: your tableview is connected with delegate and datasource.

Comment: so there is no need to extend extend UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource ? are you saying that... merly draging from tableview to delegate and datasource is enogh ? then why do we even need to   extend UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: your using default tableviewController so draging from tableview to delegate and datasource is enogh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasource is used to supply data and delegate is used to supply behaviour. UITableView asks your datasource every time it needs data to display.  It provides a lot of flexibility for how you choose to represent your underlying data model. You simply define specific methods to use in order to get table information, and iOS can call them when it needs to know something like the number of rows in a section, or the content of a particular row.

You will probably implement your own delegate mechanism in the future. It is a great design pattern which handles interaction/data transfer between objects.

Comment: but in some examples i have seen, the actually extended UITableViewDel?egate, UITableViewDataSource in the code, what is the purpose of that

Answer (score 1):

Because, the basic class adopts from UITableViewController

```c
@interface WTTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

In your storyboard you just ctrl-drag from tableview to viewController and choose delegate and dataSource.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/ you should refer this it will help u alot

Answer (score 1):

If you working with TableViewController, `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` are connected to table automatically. In case you are working with ViewControler which contains TableView, you have to add `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` like this: `@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`. In new versions of Xcode you can drag delegate and data source to table, and if you want to set delegate programmatically, you can add this two lines of codes:

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

or, equally:

```
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: he have set his delegate and datasource in storyboard.

Comment: so no need to write this.

Comment: I saw that, but question is not defined as that, he is asking generally, so I explained both ways just in case he needs it sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In viewcontroller.h file e
declare the delegate and datasource method.

```
UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

then 
connect the delegate and datasource method with viewController so 
in viewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
tableview.delegate=self;
tableview.dataSource=self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C/iOS you often implement things by having classes conform to protocols rather than subclassing classes. WTTableViewController conforms to the protocols
UITableViewDataSource: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/
and
UITableViewDelegate: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/

In MainStoryboard.storyboard you can see in the inspector to the right that the TableViewController has a custom class of WTTableViewController

The relevant methods in WTTableViewController.m:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WeatherCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...


    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
}
```

Here's some general info about protocols: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

I suggest reading a beginners book or tutorial on iOS to pick up the overall design principles otherwise many things can be quite confusing.